# Game of Thrones: Declaring a March to various adjacent territories at the same time

Tags: game-of-thrones

Consider the following scenario in Game of Thrones Board Game:

[image]

I am playing with the green pieces.

**QUESTION 1.** Can I march with two units onto area C **first**, apply the combat, and **after that** decide whether or not I will march with the third unit to B? In other words, **can I wait for the combat result to decide what will I do with the rest of my units in A?**

**QUESTION 2.** If it's the case that I can't wait for the combat result, and I must declare everything at once, **can I wait for the combat result to decide whether or not I will put a power token on area A?**

Motivation of the questions: if possible, for optimal strategy, I would like to attack the blue player first, and depending on the result, I would decide whether or not I want to march with the third unit to B. Also, I would like to be able to decide whether or not to spend a power token on area A after seeing the combat result, because if I lose the combat my pieces would retreat to A and a power token would be unneccssary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer 1** "Before resolving combat, all other non-combat movement from
the area assigned the March Order must be completed." GoT second edition rule book, page 15, 7th bullet point.

**Answer 2** It is not the case.   "If a playerleaves an area vacant before initiating combat , he must decide whether or not to establish control of the area before combat begins" GoT second edition rule book, page 24, 4th paragrqph of "establishing control of an area"

Comment: So when do I decide whether or not to place the power token?

Comment: Directly after you move the last unit out of an area you decide if you will place a power token to retain it.

Comment: I see, thanks, that answers my questions. But can you provide the sources for those claims? Once you do that I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: sure, If I remember, I do not have my rule book on my at the moment.

Comment: Updated with sources.